# Different State Variables for New Textfields in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, variables, swiftui, xcode8

I am new to SwiftUI and there is a scenario in which I can add more than one person's data and every time I *tap* on the *button*, it will collect new person's data.

The **scenario** is like this:
[image: scenario]

I add data on one textfield, it updates on every textfield because there is only one **state variable** for the textfield. My **problem** is how can I add multiple **State variables** for the textfield as the textfields have no fixed number. My code is:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldText: View {
    
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    @State var totalValue: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            
            ForEach((1...totalValue).reversed(), id: \.self) {_ in

                VStack {
                    CustomTextfield(text: $name, placeHolder: "Enter name", title: "Enter Name")
                    
                    CustomTextfield(text: $email, placeHolder: "Enter email", title: "Enter Email")
                }
            }
            
            Button {
                print("add person tapped")
                totalValue = totalValue + 1
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 60)
                        .frame(width: 180, height: 45)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(ColorName.appBlue.rawValue))
                    Text("Add another person")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(Font.custom(InterFont.bold.rawValue, size: 14))
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}

struct TextFieldText_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldText()
    }
}
```

I want to add different data on every textfield. How can I achieve it in SwiftUI?

Comment: Use arrays if names and emails. You need to have different state variables for each text field.

Comment: You don't really. I would have a List (and an array) under the button so when you press the button the values you have entered is added to the array and shown in the list and at the same time the fields are cleared so you can enter a new person. I would also consider creating a struct for person that holds the name and email, that would make it easier to work with the array and the list. This is somewhat simplified of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to handle multiple people but you have only **one** `name` and **one** `email` property.

You need an array. A *swifty* way is a custom struct

```
struct Person  {
    var name, email : String
}
```

In the view replace `name` and `email` with an empty array of `Person`

```
@State private var people = [Person]()
```

In the `ForEach` loop iterate over the indices and bind the `text` parameter to the person at given index.

I don't have your custom text fields, the code uses the default fields

```
ForEach(people.indices, id: \.self) { index in
    VStack {
        TextField("Enter name", text: $people[index].name)
        TextField("Enter email", text: $people[index].email)
    }
    .padding()
}
```

Finally in the button action add a new `Person` to `people`

```
Button {
    print("add person tapped")
    people.append(Person(name: "", email: ""))
```

Comment: from where the users came from? It is giving error: _could not find users_ in the last line `users.append(Person(name: "", email: ""))`

Comment: My bad, replace `users` with `people`

Comment: this worked but one last thing, there is no textfield on load. When I tap on button, then it is adding the textfields, I want 1 textfield for name and 1 for email there on load too.

Comment: Declare the data source with one default item `@State private var people = [Person(name: "", email: "")]`. The view shows one pair of text fields for each person in the array